# How can Multiprocessing be achieved by Programming Languages?

Tags: c, assembly, operating-system, kernel, multiprocessing

I am trying to develop a simple Operating System. Till now all programs that I developed can be run in a single processor. But when I went through a concept called Multiprocessing Systems which almost all of the latest systems are based, I got lot of doubts.

First, How can I create a program which can run in Multiprocessor systems. Is it Hardware oriented or Programmer specific?

Second I went through Parallel Programming Languages which can be helpful in Multiprocessing Systems where Java is one but C is not. Then how can an OS developed in C(Windows) can achieve Multiprocessing?

Thanks.

Comment: The operating system is responsible for *thread scheduling*, and it can schedule those threads for execution on different processors if it wants.

Comment: That's what I am asking. I know Operating System is responsible. Threads are executed in parallel in Multiprocessor Systems and if some OS is built in C which is not a parallel programming language..How is it possible?

Comment: Say what? You are developing an OS? You think that writing a program in a "parallel programming language" will make that program run on multiple processors? BTW, what is a "parallel programming language" again? Start with a good book on OS, maybe the one by Galvin, Silberschatz, Gagne.

Comment: By the time you are dealing with multi-processing, it is hardly a *simple operating system"* any longer.  I suggest that the hierarchy of complexity is single-tasking -> multi-tasking -> multi-tasking with memory protection -> multi-tasking on multiple processors/cores.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're right: a typical C program is single-processor. The statements that you write in it are expected to be executed one after the other, obeying loops and tests as required. But you can call a function in C that says "don't execute this function now: create a new Thread and execute it with that!"

```
int maxPlaces;
int piDigits;

void CalculatePi() {
   // write code to calculate pi to maxPlaces
      // Update piDigits as you go
} // CalculatePi()

int main() {
   maxPlaces = 2000000000;
// CalculatePi(); // OLD CODE: Don't do this! Instead, do...
   StartThread(CalculatePi);
   while (piDigits<=maxPlaces) {
       Print(piDigits);
   } // while
} // main()
```

If you were to execute this code with the OLD CODE, without using my (made-up) function `StartThread()`, the program would hang for a long time then print out the number 2000000000 when it finished.

But my function `StartThread()` tells the OS to create a new thread of execution on the function `CalculatePi()`, then return immediately. That means that `main()` can start to repeatedly print out the values of `piDigits` as it gets larger. There are now two threads of execution: one calculating the digits of pi, the other printing out how far it's got.

This program will work on any multi-threaded OS, even those running with only a single processor. In that case each thread will get a little bit of processor time before it is swapped to the other. If the computer has multiple processors, the OS might give one thread to one and the other to the other - the program doesn't care or (usually) know.

Parallel programming languages, however, are written such that you don't have to explicitly create new threads of execution like this. The syntax and design of the language makes it obvious when tasks can be run concurrently. C isn't like that, but you can still take advantage of concurrency with special function calls.

Comment: C with OpenMP *is* like that.  `#pragma omp parallel` on the line before a `for` loop will parallelize it with worker threads.

Answer (score 5):

If a systems-level language intrinsically supported multi-threading, what language would you use to *implement* multi-threading support in the first place?

It is the operating system that provides support for multi-threading and the distribution of threads across cores.  Languages that directly support multi-threading do so with the support of the OS.

C is a systems level language and as such can be used for *writing* operating systems.  It does not have intrinsic support for multi-threading - that would be a chicken/egg situation.  Instead an OS developer would implement multi-threading/multi-processing support perhaps using C and necessarily some assembler to access non-memory mapped processor resources necessary to support multi-threading/multi-tasking/multi-processing.

Given an operating system with multi-threading support, *application level code* written in a language such as C without intrinsic support for multi-threading can still be multi-threaded by accessing the OS API support for it.  Ultimately this is how higher-level languages *with* intrinsic support for threading support it in any case - by generating code that accesses the OS API.

For example, multi-threaded C code might look like this (simplified pseudo-code):

```
#include <os_api.h>

void thread1()
{
    for(;;)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}

void thread2()
{
    for(;;)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}

int main()
{
    OS_BeginThread( thread1 ) ;
    OS_BeginThread( thread2 ) ;
    for(;;)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

The point is that while systems-level languages such as C and C++ do not have intrinsic support for threading (because they are used to *implement* it), they are infinitely extensible through libraries, so language support for any feature is seldom a problem.  In fact the C++11 standard library includes support for threading via the `std::thread` class, so in that language at least there is an OS independent method of using multi-threading - but the implementation still relies on operating systems support.  Equally there are cross-platform C libraries for multi-threading such as pthreads that afford a level of portability across systems that support multi-threading.

Multi-threading does not in itself imply or require multi-processing of course, but it is the most usual way of taking advantage of a system with multiple execution units (be they hyperthreads, cores, or actual processors), and application performance scales well from single core to multi-core when an application is multi-threaded. Moreover multi-threading is not the only means of executing code on multiple execution units; parallel-processing may imply a much finer grained level of concurrency than simple threads.  OpenMP is a set of compiler directives and library routines support by a number of C, C++ and Fortran compilers that support code parallelism at finer granularity than only threads.